# Purpose and use of properties 'action', 'actionListener', 'actionListeners'

Tags: xpages

In a button I can see three properties `action`, `actionListener` & `actionListeners`. I tried  to use the `actionListener` property by creating a class implementing `java.awt.event.ActionListener` and implementing `actionPerformed` method and then calling the class using expression language. But nothing happened.

Even the documentation on these properties is cryptic. Can anyone explain how these properties are used and their purpose?

Comment: See if JSF documentation on this can help. See for instance this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Comment: You can't mix java.awt with that. AWT (abstract window toolkit) is for GUI components in Java (standalone) application only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use "javax.faces.event.actionlistener" and it uses processAction method.  I assume you know though that xpages uses xp:eventHandler's instead of the vanilla JSF 1.1 attributes you mentioned.